# In CSS, how to make images responsive within a flex column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My initial goal is

- stack images vertically within the viewport but never trigger an overflow. I deliberately don't use 100vh but 100% to better adapt to mobiles. It does not change the game anyway.
- images should shrink if they don't fit vertically or horizontally
- images should enlarge to fill the space
- images should not distord

I have a somewhat working codepen but I can't understand why it requires an `overflow: auto` in the child to behave the way I need.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Jean-yves-Leseigneur/pen/JjwKGpG)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {

    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;

    height: 100%;
}



.flex-parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: black;
    gap: 8px;
    height: 100%;

}

.flex-child {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    align-self: center;
   overflow: auto;
}

.image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

</style>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex-parent">
        <div class="flex-child">
            <img draggable="false" class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0010ee/fff">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-child">
            <img draggable="false" class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0010ee/fff">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any insight is welcome. I really would like to understand what goes on here. I understand a bit that there is something about *block formatting context*, but don't fully grasp it.
I tried to play with `object: contain` with no success.

Comment: Please see [ask], then put your code in a snippet demo _here_ using the editor. Also, [never link "here".](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/#here-conceals-what-users-are-clicking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like `overflow: auto`, you can set `min-height` other than `auto`. Or any `overflow` value other than `visible`.
This is necessary so that the element can shrink, because by default when `overflow: visible` - it is set to `min-height: auto`.
[Automatic Minimum Size of Flex Items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {

    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;

    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}



.flex-parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: black;
    gap: 8px;
    height: 100%;

}

.flex-child {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    align-self: center;
    /*  */
   /* overflow: auto; */
   min-height: 0;
}

.image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

</style>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex-parent">
        <div class="flex-child">
            <img draggable="false" class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0010ee/fff">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-child">
            <img draggable="false" class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0010ee/fff">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `flex-child` has no height defined. That's why it calculates it's height by combining the height of it's child elements. In this case the child is the `img` element. Which has a css height property with the value 100%. This means 100% of the parent element. But the height of the parent element depends on the height of the child elements, so we are now in an infinite loop.

That why the browser decides to calculate the height of the `img` element from the image that's rendered in the `img` element instead. The image in the `img` element has a height of 400 pixels and thus the `img` element gets a height of 400 pixels as well.

To break this infinite loop you can set `overflow: auto` (or `overflow: hidden`) on the `flex-child` element.
Or another way is to set `height: 100%` on the `flex-child` element.

That way the height of the `flex-child` element now depends on the height of the parent element instead of it's child elements. The height of the parent element is now equally distributed between al `flex-child` elements.

Comment: Thank you. If I remove `overflow: auto` and replace it with `height: 100%` in  `flex-child` then the images do not shrink when the viewport is less than 800px but only when viewport is less than 400px : scroll bars appears and both images no longer fit.
I understand your explanation, is `overflow: auto` meant to be used in such cases or is it a happy side effect ?